# Str to Pandas DF(DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to convert a str to a pandas dataframe:

The code i am using is;

`df = pd.json_normalize(data_json)`

I am getting the follwing error - any suggestions will be appreciated.

````
  File "C:\Users\python_projects\SOL_MACD\venv\test.py", line 44, in <module>
    df = pd.json_normalize(data_json)
  File "C:\Users\python_projects\SOL_MACD\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 423, in _json_normalize
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError ```
````

Comment: Could you add an example of the string you are trying to convert?

Comment: **Example of JSON:**
{"Response": "Success", "Message": "", "HasWarning": false, "Type": 100, "RateLimit": {}, "Data": {"Aggregated": false, "TimeFrom": 1553040000, "TimeTo": 1639440000, "Data": [{"time": 1553040000, "high": 0, "low": 0, "open": 0, "volumefrom": 0, "volumeto": 0, "close": 0, "conversionType": "direct", "conversionSymbol": ""}, {"time": 1553126400, "high": 0, "low": 0, "open": 0, "volumefrom": 0, "volumeto": 0, "close": 0, "conversionType": "direct", "conversionSymbol": ""}

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Are you able to describe your desired DataFrame output (which columns and how many rows). That is not clear from your JSON-example.

Comment: Apologies, i am trying to to have a datetime row aggregating by day and columns as follows - low,high,open,close,volumeto,volumefrom

Comment: This was the original dict - 

'Data': [{'time': 1553040000, 'high': 0, 'low': 0, 'open': 0, 'volumefrom': 0, 'volumeto': 0, 'close': 0, 'conversionType': 'direct', 'conversionSymbol': ''}, {'time': 1553126400, 'high': 0, 'low': 0, 'open': 0, 'volumefrom': 0, 'volumeto': 0, 'close': 0, 'conversionType': 'direct', 'conversionSymbol': ''}, {'time': 1553212800, 'high': 0, 'low': 0, 'open': 0, 'volumefrom': 0, 'volumeto': 0, 'close': 0, 'conversionType': 'direct', 'conversionSymbol': ''}

Comment: I am not sure, that I understand. Try this: pd.DataFrame(data_json['data']['Data']). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I am essentially after this:
```
   low  high open close  volumefrom  volumeto 
date time

2014-11-28  0 0 0 0  0 0
2014-11-29  0 0 0 0  0 0
```

Comment: I see no date in the either of the two previous examples you provided. How is that obtained?

Comment: I am essentially after this https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*QgQoKjqFrlYZOBPQsI-61A.png

Comment: This here: 
df = pd.json_normalize(data, ['Data'])
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='s')
df = df[['datetime', 'low', 'high', 'open',
             'close', 'volumefrom', 'volumeto']]

Answer (score 0):

the NotImplementedError occurs when an abstract method lacks the required derived class to override this method.so you can't have a dataframe just with a str it must have columns.
For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
My_dataframe = {
     Col_1 = ["jack", "james"]
     Col_2 = ["white", "harden"]
Dataframe = pd.dataframe(My_dataframe)
}
```

Comment: Can you please review the following:

df = pd.json_normalize(data, ['Data'])
    df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='s')
    df = df[['datetime', 'low', 'high', 'open',
             'close', 'volumefrom', 'volumeto']]